# Variable importance by "mlr3filters" does not work in "mlr3proba" after preprocessing data with "mlr3pipelines"

Tags: machine-learning, mlr3, data-preprocessing

Running the code below using `mlr3proba` and `mlr3pipelines` and `mlr3filters` packages of R to implement `rpart` algorithm on a preporcessed dataset and performing "variable importance",  shows an error:

```
task <- tsk("iris")

learner <- lrn("classif.rpart")

learner <- po("encode") %>>% po("scale") %>>% po("learner", learner)      # preprocessing

learner <- GraphLearner$new(learner)  #applying learner on a graph in mlr3pipelines

filter <- flt("importance", learner = learner)    #using filter for variable importance

filter$calculate(task)
```

```
#Error: 

Error in learner$importance() : attempt to apply non-function
```

But when I run the code above, without preprocessing, it works:

```
task <- tsk("iris")

learner <- lrn("classif.rpart")

filter <- flt("importance", learner = learner)

filter$calculate(task)

as.data.table(filter)
```

```
#Results:

        feature     score
1:  Petal.Width  88.96940
2: Petal.Length  81.34496
3: Setal.Length  54.09606
4:  Sepal.Width  36.01309
```

So, what is wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Five upvotes and no answer in my onion means you probably stumbled on a bug. Perhaps post an issue here: https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3pipelines/issues and explain that a GraphLearner tagged with the importance property can not be used to filter features by because it did not inherit the importance extractor from the base learner.

Comment: Indeed, a bug / missing functionality. This PR addresses your question: https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3/pull/648